# Unterschied zwischen "untersagen" und "verbieten"?

Tags: synonym

**Beispiel**

> Die Spielen von Musikinstrumenten während der Mittagsruhe ist **untersagt** und auf zwei Stunden am Tag beschränkt.

Ist *"untersagt"* im Kontext "besseres" Deutsch? Kann ich sagen *"Ich untersage alle Fahrräder"* oder *"verbote Musik während der Mittagsruhe"*?

Comment: Verboten und untersagt sind ziemlich gleichwertig; verboten ist etwas allgemeiner verwendbar. Es müsste übrigens "*Das* Spielen von ... *ist* ... untersagt" heißen.

Comment: "Ich verbiete Musik (zu spielen/hören)" kann man sagen - "verbote" dagegen nicht. "Ich untersage alle Fahrräder" ist ein komplettes Rätsel. Fahrradfahren oder Fahrradhandel kann man untersagen, aber Fahrräder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### [untersagen](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=untersagen), [verbieten](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=verbieten&view=1)

Beide Wörter werden heute in der Tat synonym verwendet. Ein *"Verbot"* ist aber manchmal etwas zu harsch, so dass gelegentlich vor allem in offiziellen Mitteilungen *"untersagen"* verwendet wird. Das klingt *"amtlicher"* und ist nicht ganz so streng wie ein Verbot, das Eltern ihren Kindern gegenüber aussprechen. In der ersten Person Singular wird *"untersagen"* fast nie verwendet.

Beide Varianten gehören zu der (auch gehobenen) Standardsprache.

Deine beiden Beispiele kann man also wie folgt formulieren:

> - Fahrradfahren [ist] verboten. Fahrradfahren ist untersagt. Ich verbiete [Dir], Fahrrad zu fahren.
> - Laute Musik [ist] während der Mittagsruhe verboten. Ich verbiete es Dir, laute Musik zu hören. Musizieren währen der Mittagsruhe ist untersagt.

Es gibt keinen wesentlichen (juristischen) Unterschied zwischen einer Untersagung und einem Verbot, allerdings gelten Verbote auch außerhalb der Rechtssprechung (z.B. in den Naturgesetzen). Vergleiche hierzu auch:

> *"Untersagt wird nur, was bisher erlaubt gewesen; verbothen auch das, was nie erlaubt gewesen ist."*  <sup>[J. A. Eberhard 1837](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbot#cite_note-2)</sup>

Comment: *Untersagen* wird generell im Aktiv kaum verwendet.

Comment: Ich sehe nicht wie "untersagen" weniger harsch klingen soll, insbesondere da es eher im amtlichen Gebrauch vorkommt.

Comment: Mir ist so, als würde untersagen im Aktiv durchaus verwendet. Der Amtsschimmel untersagt nämlich persönlich, wenn es etwas zu untersagen gibt...

Answer (score 7):

Die Wörter "untersagen" und "verbieten" sind Synonyme. "Untersagen" ist aber etwas antiquierter und klingt etwas verstaubt.

> Das Ballspielen und Herumlaufen auf den Gängen ist verboten.
> Das Ballspielen und Herumlaufen auf den Gängen ist untersagt.

Du kannst übrigens keine Fahrräder verbieten oder untersagen. Streng genommen kann man nicht einmal Schusswaffen und Drogen verbieten, denn man kann nur Tätigkeiten erlauben oder verbieten:

> Das Mitführen von Waffen ist verboten.
> Das Mitführen von Waffen ist untersagt.
>
> Die Herstellung, der Besitz und die Weitergabe von Drogen sind verboten.
> Die Herstellung, der Besitz und die Weitergabe von Drogen sind untersagt.

Manchmal hört oder liest man Sätze wie "In Deutschland sind Pumpguns verboten." Damit ist gemeint, dass die Einfuhr, der Besitz, die Herstellung, die Weitergabe usw. von Pumpguns verboten sind. Die Gegenstände selbst können ebenso wenig illegal sein wie Menschen. (Es gibt keine illegalen Einwanderer, sondern Menschen, die illegal eingewandert sind.) Wenn eine einsame und vergessene Pumpgun irgendwo in Deutschland auf einem Dachboden langsam verrostet, wird die Pumpgun nicht dafür bestraft, dass sie eine Pumpgun ist. Aber ihr Besitzer kann ausgeforscht werden, und der kann dann bestraft werden, weil er das Ding besessen hat.

---

Häufig werden Verbote auch als Ellipsen formuliert, wobei ich diese Verkürzungen nur im Zusammenhang mit "verbieten", nicht aber mit "untersagen" kenne:

> Radfahren verboten
> Rauchen verboten
> Auf den Boden spucken verboten

Das letzte Beispiel wird häufig auch so formuliert:

> Nicht auf den Boden spucken

---

Noch zu deinen konkreten Fragen:

Sagen kannst du alles, nur ist es nicht immer richtig.

**"Ich untersage alle Fahrräder"** Nein, das ist zwar grammatisch korrekt, aber syntaktisch nicht in Ordnung. Du kannst keine Gegenstände, sondern nur Tätigkeiten untersagen. Aber das geht:

> Ich untersage das Radfahren.
> Ich untersage den Besitz und die Herstellung von Fahrrädern.

**"verbote Musik während der Mittagsruhe"**. Das ist kein grammatisch korrekter deutscher Satz. Ich weiß nicht genau was du gemeint hast. Ich glaube, du könntest einen dieser Sätze gemeint haben: "Ich verbiete Musik während der Mittagsruhe." oder "Musik während der Mittagsruhe ist verboten."

Streng genommen ist auch Musik keine Tätigkeit. Aber jeder der das liest, wird erkennen, dass das Abspielen von Musik und das Musizieren gemeint sind. Niemand wird glauben, dass damit ausgedrückt werden soll, dass das Komponieren von Musik verboten ist, oder dass man in der Mittagspause keine Medien, auf denen Musik gespeichert ist, mit sich führen darf.

Allerdings ist es bei Verboten unüblich, sie in Aktiv-Sätzen zu formulieren. Üblich sind Passiv-Sätze, in denen nicht erwähnt wird, wer das Verbot erlassen hat. Ausnahme: Der Erlasser des Verbots möchte die Wirksamkeit des Verbots durch seine/ihre Autorität unterstreichen. (Mutter zum Kind: "Ich verbiete dir zu dieser Party zu gehen!")

Es schafft auch Klarheit, wenn man den etwas schwammigen Begriff "Mittagsruhe" durch konkrete Uhrzeiten ersetzt.

Also:

> Von 12:00 bis 14:00 Uhr sind Musizieren und lautes Abspielen von Musik verboten.

Comment: Naja, als ich klein war, und meine Mutter mir etwas *untersagen* wollte, hat sie stets den Aktiv verwendet ;) Also was ich sagen will, du solltest noch sowas wie *offiziell* einbauen, an der Stelle, wo du behauptest, dass das Formulieren von Verboten nicht im Aktiv üblich ist.

Comment: Ich stimme zu, aber Mittagsruhe ist von eins bis drei. :)